# How do I convert a list of strings to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My list is something like this,

```
['"third:4"', '"first:7"', '"second:8"']
```

I want to convert this into a dictionary like this...

```
{"third": 4, "first": 7, "second": 8}
```

How do I do this in Python?

Comment: How do you get the list? If you create it by yourself, don't do it...

Answer (score 6):

Here are two possible solutions, one that gives you string values and one that gives you int values:

```
>>> lst = ['"third:4"', '"first:7"', '"second:8"']
>>> dict(x[1:-1].split(':', 1) for x in lst)
{'second': '8', 'third': '4', 'first': '7'}
>>> dict((y[0], int(y[1])) for y in (x[1:-1].split(':', 1) for x in lst))
{'second': 8, 'third': 4, 'first': 7}
```

However, for the sake of readability, you could split the conversion into two steps:

```
>>> lst = ['"third:4"', '"first:7"', '"second:8"']
>>> dct = dict(x[1:-1].split(':', 1) for x in lst)
>>> {k: int(v) for k, v in dct.iteritems()}
```

Of course this has some overhead since you create a dict twice - but for a small list it doesn't matter.

Comment: Your values are still strings

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> data
['"third:4"', '"first:7"', '"second:8"']
>>> dict((k,int(v)) for k,v in (el.strip('\'"').split(':') for el in data))
{'second': 8, 'third': 4, 'first': 7}
```

or

```
>>> data = ['"third:4"', '"first:7"', '"second:8"']
>>> def convert(d):
        for el in d:
            key, num = el.strip('\'"').split(':')
            yield key, int(num)


>>> dict(convert(data))
{'second': 8, 'third': 4, 'first': 7}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def listToDic(lis):
    dic = {}
    for item in lis:
        temp = item.strip('"').split(':')
        dic[temp[0]] = int(temp[1])
    return dic
```

Comment: -1 this will not work, remove `""` from the string first, and also the 3rd line of your `listToDic` function should be `for item in lsit`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary OOPS~I didn't see that ", but I don't think it deserves a down-vote. Um,thank you anyway.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

With `map and dict` it is very straight forward.

### syntax for map

`map(func, iterables)`

`to_dict` will return `key, value` which will be consumed by `dict`

```
def to_dict(item):  
      return item[0].replace('"',''), int(item[1].replace('"', ''))

>>> items
6: ['"third:4"', '"first:7"', '"second:8"']
>>> dict(map(to_dict, [item.split(':') for item in items]))
7: {'first': 7, 'second': 8, 'third': 4}
```

`help(dict)`

```
class dict(object)   
     dict() -> new empty dictionary
     dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
     (key, value) pairs

     dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
     d = {}
     for k, v in iterable:
         d[k] = v
    dict(**kwargs) -> new dictionary initialized with the name=value pairs
       in the keyword argument list.  For example:  dict(one=1, two=2)
```

### Final Code

```
>>> dict(map(to_dict, [item.split(':') for item in items]))
```